# Expectation and kth factorial moment

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, expected-value, moments

I'm working through an assignment so I don't expect to be handed the answer. I just need to ask about the equation itself.

The question is:

Show that

[image]

When working with the standard normal distribution.

In the previous part of the question I derived that

[image]

So I'm presuming that is pertinent but I'm not sure where to start and what does the (2k)! mean in this context?

Hope someone can help as I'm just not even sure where to begin Googling this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you started, $(2k)! = (2k)(2k-1)(2k-2)... (1) $

Also, the term $t^{2k} $ is somewhat redundant (appears on both LHS and RHS of the equation).

Secondly, the result you have proved can be used to set up a recursive equation, as $E (X^{2k-2})=E (X^{2 (k-1)}) $.  You can also fairly obviously figure out that $E (X^{2})=1$.

That should be enough to get you started

**update (based on comment)**

If you do a second iteration, you should get 
$$E [X^{2k}]=(2k-1)(2 (k-1)-1)E [X^{2 (k-2)}]=(2k-1)(2k-3)E [X^{2 (k-2)}]$$

The next iteration will give $(2k-1)(2k-3)(2k-5)$ and so on.  You may notice that instead of decreasing by $1$, each term decreases by $2$.  If you put those terms back (and divide them out again) the answer follows.

Comment: I can see it but I can't quite get to it. I essentially want to get $\left ( 2k-1 \right )E\left [ X^{2(k-1)} \right ]\rightarrow \left ( \frac{1}{2} \right )^{k}$ right?

The only thing I can't figure out is how to get the k term out of the expectation.